# Can i read 2 .csv files using Scenario Outline in Karate

Tags: karate

My requirements is I have one Request file (.csv) and one Response (.csv) file.
I want to read request file for sending the payload and when match the response to Response.csv file.

Is there a way i can achieve this in Karate ?

Comment: I am linking you to one answer that *may* help - but if it doesn't - please assume that the answer to your question is NO